# Access SQLWarnings called via StoredProcedure.execute() in Spring

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures

I am calling Stored Procedures by `extending` `StoredProcedure` class in `Spring`. My Stored Procedures are generating warnings which I want to log.

This will remove the effort needed to re-execute StoredProcedures with dummy values to see what warning is coming and what needs to be fixed.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Warnings are already logged by default by the `JdbcTemplate`. Drawback is that you would have to enable debug logging for that class.

For log back adding this to your `logback.xml` will enable it.

```
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTemplate" level="DEBUG" />
```